# Using 'AND' in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, select

I have a `Users` table and a `Groups` table. Users can be in multiple groups via a 'UserInGroup' table and Groups can have a 'GroupTypeId'.

```
[User]
--------------
Id | Name
1  | Bob
2  | James

[UserInGroup]
-----------------
UserId | GroupId
1        1
1        2

[Group]
Id | Name      | TypeId
------------------------
1  | Directors | 1
2  | IT        | 1
3  | London    | 2
```

I want to create a query to return for example users that are in both 'Directors' AND 'London' (rather than 'Directors' OR 'London'). However, I only want to AND groups of a different 'Type', I want to OR groups of the same type. I could do with having a separate table per group type but I can't as they are created dynamically.

Ideally I want to be able to query users who are in 'Directors' OR 'IT' AND 'London'.

What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is commonly known as `Relational Division`.

```
SELECT  a.Name
FROM    [user] a
        INNER JOIN UserInGroup b
            ON a.ID = b.UserID
        INNER JOIN [Group] c
            ON b.groupID = c.TypeId
WHERE   c.Name IN ('Directors','London')
GROUP   BY a.Name
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/155b2/3)
- [SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

But if a `UNIQUE` constraint was not enforce on `GROUP` for every `USER`, `DISTINCT` keywords is needed to filter out unique groups:

```
SELECT  a.Name
FROM    [user] a
        INNER JOIN UserInGroup b
            ON a.ID = b.UserID
        INNER JOIN [Group] c
            ON b.groupID = c.TypeId
WHERE   c.Name IN ('Directors','London')
GROUP   BY a.Name
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT c.Name) = 2
```

---

OUTPUT *from both queries*

```
╔══════╗
║ NAME ║
╠══════╣
║ Bob  ║
╚══════╝
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that's very helpful. Also, I now have a name for it do some research. Thanks again.

Comment: what's the reason for unaccepting this answer? anyway, what would you like to know more so i can improve my answer.

Comment: Sorry, thanks so much for the reply but I don't think you answered my question fully. My problem is that I want to use AND when the TypeId column is different, but OR when it's the same.

So...I want all users in 'Directors' OR 'IT' AND 'London'.

Comment: Also, in you SQLFiddle you seemed to be joining Group on it's TypeId column rather than its Id column. The TypeId is a discriminator field.

Here's the fiddle I'm currently playing with: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/918cc/5.

Comment: That does work. The only draw back is that the query can be any number of groups, so I don't always know what COUNT to check against for each type. All I will have is a load of group ids. How does this look? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/987be/8

Comment: how is `UserInGroup` related with `[Group]`? by `groupID = TypeId` or by `groupID = Id`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26957/discussion-between-j-w-and-siegemos)

Answer (score 0):

I arrived at the following solution (with help from J W and [this article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)):

```
SELECT  
  u.Name UserName
FROM [User] u
INNER JOIN [UserInGroup] uig
  ON uig.UserId = u.Id
INNER JOIN [Group] g
  ON g.Id = uig.GroupId
WHERE 
  g.Id IN (1,2,3) -- these are the passed in groupids
GROUP BY 
  u.Name
having count(distinct g.TypeId)
  = (select count(distinct g1.TypeId) 
     from [group] g1 where g1.Id IN (1,2,3))
```

This allows me to group the relational division by a discriminator field. An alternative would be this:

```
SELECT  a.Name
FROM    [User] a
    INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT  b.UserID
      FROM    UserInGroup b
              INNER JOIN [Group] c
                  ON b.groupID = c.Id
      WHERE   c.Name IN ('Directors','IT')
      GROUP   BY b.UserID
      HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT c.Name) >= 1
    ) b ON a.ID = b.UserID
    INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT  DISTINCT b.UserID
      FROM    UserInGroup b
              INNER JOIN [Group] c
                  ON b.groupID = c.Id
      WHERE   c.Name = 'London'
    ) c ON a.ID = c.UserID
```

With an extra join for each GroupTypeId. Execution plans look similar, so I went with the first option.